# RedirectStandardOutput Doesn't Fire Until Console Process Finishes

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, console-application, outputstream

I have a strange issue that has come up. I have written a windows form app in C# using Visual Studio 2012/13. My app opens a console application and captures the standard and error output from it as it runs, then prints that output to a text box in the windows form. It used to work great, but I must've changed something that inadvertantly caused this functionality to stop working.

It now only prints the output from the console app in the windows form AFTER the console app finishes and quits. I have been banging my head against this for a bit now and am at a loss. I upgraded from Visual Studio 2012 to 2013, but the project wasn't changed, upgraded, or anything like that, so I don't believe that's the culprit. Any help would be appreciated!

I believe I have the proper code set up to capture output as it is printed (this used to work anyway):

```
transporterProcess.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
transporterProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
transporterProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
transporterProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
transporterProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
transporterProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
transporterProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(printOutput);
transporterProcess.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(printError);
transporterProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(process_Exited);

...

transporterProcess.Start();
transporterProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
transporterProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();

private void printOutput(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
    {   // output is a global StringBuilder object
        output.Clear();
        output.Append(outLine.Data + Environment.NewLine);
        string update = output.ToString();
        updateTextfromStandardOutput = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => this.ThreadProcSafeStandardOutput(update)));
        this.updateTextfromStandardOutput.Start();
    }
}

    private void printError(object sendingProcess,
        DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
       // pretty much identical to the above code
    }

    private void ThreadProcSafeStandardOutput(string update)
    {
        this.setText(update);
    }

    private void ThreadProcSafeStandardError(string update)
    {
        this.setText(update);
    }

    private void setText(string text)
    {
        if (tbxOutput.InvokeRequired || listViewFilesToTransfer.InvokeRequired)
        {
            setTextCallback d = new setTextCallback(setText);
            tbxOutput.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
          ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you set `UseShellExecute = false`, `RedirectStandardOuput = true` and `RedirectStandardError = true` on your `ProcessStartInfo` object?

Comment: This is entirely normal.  A redirected program writes its output into an internal buffer.  If it doesn't write enough text to fill the buffer to capacity, and doesn't itself force the buffer to flush, then you won't see anything until the buffer *has* to be flushed, at program exit.  Nothing you can do about that if you don't have the source code for the program.

Comment: @RichardDeeming Sorry, I added that bit of code I had left out of my question.

Comment: @HansPassant Is there a way for me to flush the buffer from the calling application before the called process ends? I DO have access to the console process it is calling (it is written in C++, if that helps).

Comment: @HansPassant I added output flushing to the called application, and that solves the problem, which is great, but feels like a bandage instead of a proper fix. I didn't used to have to do this, what could've changed? Is there some other way to request the called application do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added output flushing to the called application, and that solves the problem as proposed by @HansPassant, though it feels a bit like a bandage, but at least it works.

Comment: Could you share your new code? I have same problem!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `EnableRaisingEvents` true

```
transporterProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Comment: Sorry I did have that, but I didn't put that bit in my example code. I've added it above. Thanks!

Comment: Oh I meant to say that I already had this bit in my code, not that it was a fix for the issue. Sadly, it is still broken :(